# Content security policy directive blocks dynamically loaded inline scripts

Tags: reactjs, content-security-policy, react-helmet, helmet.js

I am adding the following CSP directives for an express app using helmet.
and in some cases, i am loading dynamically a script tag in my react app using react-helmet.
but the CSP blocks the script from running. giving the following error in client console:

```
Refused to load the script 'data:application/javascript;base64,KCgpID0+IHsKICAgICd1c2Ugc3RyaWN0JwogICAgY29uc3Qgbm9vcCA9ICgpID0+IHt9CiAgICBjb25zdCBkYXRhbGF5ZXIgPSB3aW5kb3cuZGF0YUxheWVyCiAgICB3aW5kb3cuZ2EgPSAod2luZG93LmdhID09PSB2b2lkIDApID8gbm9vcCA6IHdpbmRvdy5nYQogICAgaWYgKGRhdGFsYXllcikgewogICAgICAgIC8vIGV4ZWN1dGUgY2FsbGJhY2sgaWYgZXhpc3RzLCBzZWUgaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2ltb2FoYXZhLmNvbS9ndG0tdGlwcy91c2UtZXZlbnR0aW1lb3V0LWV2ZW50Y2FsbGJhY2svCiAgICAgICAgaWYgKHR5cGVvZiBkYXRhbGF5ZXIucHVzaCA9PT0gJ2Z1bmN0aW9uJykgewogICAgICAgICAgICBkYXRhbGF5ZXIucHVz...RyeSB7CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIHNldFRpbWVvdXQob2JqLmV2ZW50Q2FsbGJhY2ssIHRpbWVvdXQpCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgfSBjYXRjaChlcnJvcikge30KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIH0KICAgICAgICAgICAgfQogICAgICAgIH0KICAgICAgICAvLyBwcmV2ZW50IHBhZ2UgZGVsYXksIHNlZSBodHRwczovL2RldmVsb3BlcnMuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9vcHRpbWl6ZQogICAgICAgIGlmIChkYXRhbGF5ZXIuaGlkZSAmJiBkYXRhbGF5ZXIuaGlkZS5lbmQpIHsKICAgICAgICAgICAgdHJ5IHsKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGRhdGFsYXllci5oaWRlLmVuZCgpCiAgICAgICAgICAgIH0gY2F0Y2ggKGVycm9yKSB7fQogICAgICAgIH0KICAgIH0KfSkoKQ==' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' *.gravatar.com *.segment.io cdn.talkjs.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com *.calendly.com calendly.com p.typekit.net use.typekit.net maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com *.paypalobjects.com *.paypal.com *.bluesnap.com songbirdstag.cardinalcommerce.com songbird.cardinalcommerce.com *.cardinalcommerce.com js.intercomcdn.com *.intercom.io *.auth0.com *.filestackapi.com *.fullstory.com fullstory.com js.hs-analytics.net js.hs-scripts.com js.hs-banner.com browser.sentry-cdn.com cdn.mxpnl.com snap.licdn.com assets.customer.io connect.facebook.net *.facebook.com *.googleapis.com *.googletagmanager.com *.googleadservices.com *.google-analytics.com *.gstatic.com *.googleusercontent.com *.google.com googleads.g.doubleclick.net tpc.googlesyndication.com securepubads.doubleclick.net 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

following https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#Unsafe_inline_script it should allow inline scripts.

What am i missing from my configuration ?

The express server side:

```js
    expressApp.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
      directives: {
        reportUri:      '/report-csp-violation',
        defaultSrc:     ['*', 'data:', 'blob:'],
        scriptSrc:      [
          '\'self\'',
          ...trustedDomains,
          '\'unsafe-inline\'',
          '\'unsafe-eval\'',
        ],
        styleSrc:       ['*', '\'unsafe-inline\'', 'data:'],
        workerSrc:      ['*', '\'unsafe-inline\'', 'data:', 'blob:'],
        frameAncestors: ['\'none\''],
        baseUri:        ['\'self\''],
        imgSrc:         ['*', 'blob:', 'data:'],
      },
  }));
```

React app:

```
    <Helmet>
      <script async defer>
        {googleTagManagerCode}
      </script>
    </Helmet>
```

The original CSP report sent by browser:

```js
{
  "document-uri": "https://app.....com",
  "referrer": "",
  "violated-directive": "script-src-elem",
  "effective-directive": "script-src-elem",
  "original-policy": "report-uri /report-csp-violation; default-src * data: blob:; script-src 'self' *.gravatar.com *.segment.io cdn.talkjs.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com *.calendly.com calendly.com p.typekit.net use.typekit.net maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com *.paypalobjects.com *.paypal.com *.bluesnap.com songbirdstag.cardinalcommerce.com songbird.cardinalcommerce.com *.cardinalcommerce.com js.intercomcdn.com *.intercom.io *.auth0.com *.filestackapi.com *.fullstory.com fullstory.com js.hs-analytics.net js.hs-scripts.com js.hs-banner.com browser.sentry-cdn.com cdn.mxpnl.com snap.licdn.com assets.customer.io connect.facebook.net *.facebook.com *.googleapis.com *.googletagmanager.com *.googleadservices.com *.google-analytics.com *.gstatic.com *.googleusercontent.com *.google.com googleads.g.doubleclick.net tpc.googlesyndication.com securepubads.doubleclick.net 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline' data:; worker-src * 'unsafe-inline' data: blob:; frame-ancestors 'none'; base-uri 'self'; img-src * blob: data:",
  "disposition": "enforce",
  "blocked-uri": "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=....
  "status-code": 0,
  "script-sample": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to add 'data:' to your script-src like this: script-src 'self' data: ...trustedDomains